# How to include a javascript file in the HTML?

Tags: javascript

I currently have my JS code in a  element inside HTML and it works fine. As soon as I swap it with a  with src="myjs.js" it stops working...why? So I need to addeventlisteners in HTML to the root?

Comment: You're probably getting the path wrong.

Comment: Can you post the html where you are referencing the js file?

Comment: And is there any JavaScript Errors in the console?

Comment: There is not enough information in this question to help you. There good be different reasons. Path wrong, script located at the wrong position, missing dependencies, etc. It's all just guessing.

Comment: use google to find some basic tutorials, they will help you better than we could using the description you have given.

Comment: Why was this question closed? It's suggested that the question could be 'improved' but then no answer would follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your script reference is located in the `HEAD` section and the code looks for elements in the body which was not yet initialized.

Try wrapping your code in an `onload` event handler like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    // Javascript code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `<script ...>` to `<script ...></script>`.