# How do you pull JavaScript code into an external script file?

Tags: javascript

I have my core web-app code in the header right now in a  tag but I want to move it to a separate file. When I do that an link it everything stops working. Basically the code first adds a listener onDeviceReady and from then on there are button click listeners, as well as acceleration event methods (this is a phonegap app).

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

This is the code the way I have it now:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javvscript" charset="utf-8" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
        startButton.addEventListener("click", startWatch, false);
        var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
        stopButton.addEventListener("click", stopWatch, false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The charset attribute isn't needed in script tag and have you tried debugging with the browser's dev tools?

Comment: Perhaps if you show us your new code we could tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Just try to use Firebug and Network Monitoring.

Comment: None of you guys are qualified web developers. This was a trick question - it's called "can you find the error". Haha

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458482/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-the-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered spelling "javascript" correctly?